# Cannot add WebTestPlugin to .webtest

Tags: c#, webtest

I have a WebTest in Visual Studio. I have created a custom `WebTestPlugin` in my test project which references a bunch of assemblies. Now when I click `Add Web Test Plug-in` I get an error dialog saying:

`Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.`

I have checked project output and the file exists there. I have also run procmon and sure enough when I click `Add Web Test Plug-in` the computer scans lots of locations and does find a number of matches.

Any clues to why this is happening?

Comment: Note the phrase `or one of its dependencies` in the error message.

Comment: @AdrianHHH Yes I know. I fixed it temporarily by adding the file to one of the folders I saw being scanned with procmon and now it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your customs plug-in uses objects from some other assemblies. Those assemblies has to be referred when you reference WebTestPlugIn.

Comment: My WebTestPlugin is in the same project as the .webtest.